# Растягивание блоков в css

Tags: html, css

я только начинаю учить html и css,можете подсказать пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при изменениях размера экрана, блоки, которые не вошли скрывались полностью, а не обрезались как сейчас у меня. Вот когда окно полностью открыто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда окно свернуто:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```css
div.blocks {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    border: 1px solid var(--tomato);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 80px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="blocks">
            <div class="item">1</div>
            <div class="item">2</div>
            <div class="item">3</div>
            <div class="item">4</div>
            <div class="item">5</div>
            <div class="item">6</div>
            <div class="item">7</div>
            <div class="item">8</div>
            <div class="item">9</div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте высоту контейнеру и перенос для флекса:

```css
div.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 1px solid var(--tomato);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 80px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="blocks">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)